# C# regular expressions. Get nth occurrence

Tags: c#, regex

hi i am trying to split a string using regx. How do i get the nth occurrence of a pattern so i could assign it to a string?

```
var myString = "1.2.300.4";
var pattern = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)");

var major = pattern.Occurrence(1); //first occurrence
var minor = pattern.Occurrence(2) //second occurrence
var build = pattern.Occurrence(3) //third occurrence
var revision = pattern.Occurrence(4) // forth occurrence
```

something to that effect but in regex.

is there a way to choose the occurrence in the regex pattern itself?
eg;

```
var major = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)$1");
var minor = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)$2");
var build = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)$3");
var revision = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)$4");
```

Comment: why not `myString.Split('.')` and get an array back with each number as string.

Comment: You could also just use the [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class to parse this for you.

Comment: @Habib. string.split crossed my mind before but as you now say it i can see how it will work. thanks.

Comment: Please move your answer into an actual answer. Answers should not be embedded within a question (it breaks the Stack Exchange model).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Match` to find the first, and then `NextMatch` on each match to get the next.

```
var major = pattern.Match(myString);
var minor = major.NextMatch();
var build = minor.NextMatch();
var revision = build.NextMatch();
```

If you don't want to lazily iterate the matches you can use `Matches` to parse the whole string and then get the matches (if you want) by index):

```
var allmatches = pattern.Matches(myString);
var major = allmatches[0];
//...
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. This is close to what i was looking for and it works.

Comment: so is there a way to to do the match inside of the regex pattern? i edited my eg. above to show what i mean.

Comment: @user2820801 That's basically the second example, assuming you don't have a problem eagerly parsing the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method like;

```
var myString = "1.2.300.4";
var array = myString.Split(new char[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var element in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine (element);
}
```

Outputw will be;

```
1
2
300
4
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO.`](http://ideone.com/OucMlO)</kbd>

As an alternative, using [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) could be better option for some cases. Like;

```
Version v = new Version("1.2.300.4");
Console.WriteLine (v.Major);
Console.WriteLine (v.Minor);
Console.WriteLine (v.Build);
Console.WriteLine (v.Revision);
```

Output will be;

```
1
2
300
4
```

Comment: What if the string has 100 matches and he only wants the first 5?  This eagerly parses the whole thing.

Comment: @Servy You are totally right but OP doesn't mentioned this kind of huge matches :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Split('.').`

The result will be an array.

```
var myString = "1.2.300.4";
var myResults = myString.Split('.');

var major = myResults[0]; //first occurrence
var minor = myResults[1]; //second occurrence
var build = myResults[2]; //third occurrence
var revision = myResults[3]; // forth occurrence
```

Comment: yes thats what i did first thanks. but i am learning regex and would like to do it in regex.

Comment: and this would be the most useful answer if the string was longer and had more '.', and you only wanted to get a subset of occurrences.

Comment: @user2820801 Thanks.  Based on your comment "How do i get the nth" I thought you may want just the 3rd or say 7th match, not all of them in a row.

Answer (score 1):

```
var version = Version.Parse("1.2.300.4");

var major = version.Major;
var minor = version.Minor;
var build = version.Build;
var revision = version.Revision;
```

Comment: wow thanks for this. It will be very helpful in the future when coding my about Form.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved...**

This is as close as i can get to the idea i have in my head using Regex. And it works for a string of any known length.

```
var myString = "1.2.300.4.50.6000.70";
var pattern = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)");
var match = pattern.Matches(myString);

var secondOccurrence = match[1]; // 2
var fifthOccurrence = match[5];  // 6000
```

Thanks everyone for your help.